# Homeomorphism between $\mathcal{C}(X,\Omega Y)$ and $\mathcal{C}(\Sigma X, Y)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, loop-spaces

It is easy to see that there is a natural *bijection* between $\mathcal{C}(X,\Omega Y)$ and $\mathcal{C}(\Sigma X, Y)$, where $\Omega Y$ is the based loop space, $\Sigma X$ is reduced suspension, $X$ and $Y$ are based spaces.

Now $\mathcal{C}(*,*)$ and also $\Omega Y$ can be given the compact-open topology. Is the natural bijection mentioned above actually a homeomorhpism with this topology?

I can prove this is true if I assume $X$ is a compact space.
I have shown that there is an obvious map $\Phi : \mathcal{C}(X,\Omega Y)\to \mathcal{C}(X\times S^1, Y)$ and $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. From $\text{Im}{\Phi}$ I can define a map into $\mathcal{C}(\Sigma X,Y)$, but to show that this map is continuous I need $X$ to be compact. Then the composition is actually the natural bijection.

Is compactness of $X$ necessary to prove the statement? Can it be generalized to say locally compact spaces or compactly generated spaces?

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the property doesn't hold for general topological spaces, but only for a subclass. I don't know that subclass by heart :-/, by a friend mentioned it a few days ago.

Comment: I did just look up my lecture notes (category theory example): On [compactly generated topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space) the property should hold. It might hold for larger classes of spaces as well. It was only used as an example for adjoints and we didn't go into details.

Comment: @RolfSievers, Can you provide me some more details? The closest result that I could find was [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces). But that doesn't exactly apply to my question!

Comment: I don't actually know that much myself, but I can try writing an answer from my abysmal notes (sorry, I didn't expect to actually use that example).

Comment: As it's still Christmas right now, I'm commanded of to the dinner table. Might drive my grandparents back home afterwards. If no one else with actual knowledge chimes in in the meantime, I'll have a look afterwards.

Comment: That's fine. I'll give it some more thought in the meantime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Rolf Sievers already indicated in the comments, this is true if you work in the [category of compactly generated spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+topological+space). But be aware that the function spaces do not carry the compact-open topology in this situation, but the compactly generated refinement of it instead.

If you don't want to modify the topology on the function spaces, you have to put stronger conditions on one of the spaces: If $X$ is locally compact, $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism using the regular compact-open topology and any space $Y$. A proof of this appears in Tammo tom Diecks book on algebraic topology (see Theorem 2.4.11 using $\Sigma X\cong S^1\wedge X$).

Comment: I just want to clear one little thing. I worked through the details of the theorem. Along the line, I needed to use $(Z^Y)^X\wedge(X\wedge Y) = ((Z^Y)^X)\wedge X)\wedge Y$, where $X$, $Y$ are locally compact. Is this true?